# How i can add relative path of image in Block Body Drupal7?

Tags: php, drupal-7, block

Previously my images were present in default/files folder ,i want to move them in theme specific images . priorly i accessed them via   but i want to give relative path of themes images folder now in block body .

Can anyone please guide how it can be achieved . I assume my folder is not present at root level so `<img src="/sites/all/themes/.." >` will not work .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refering to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/58330) you should use [`base_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7) function and [`path_to_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7) :

Example :

```
<img src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/' ?>images/img.jpg" />
```

Comment: Issue was resolved by assigning permissions to administrator that was the reason why php code was not executed .